# QWebView - jquery script

Tags: qt, qwebview, iscroll4

I’m developping a simple HTML5 interface for an embedded system and i’ve decided to use iscroll4 plugin ( http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 ) to animate a bit the scrolling in different containers.

The problem is that this plugin/script is not working. Also, I’m not receiving any errors on console if i’m enabling developing extras setting.

Also, i’ve tried to load directly this link : http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/ in a QWebView object, but doesn’t work too.

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you made a qrc file with the embedded files ?

Comment: Yes and then i've made a simple qt project where i've tried to load the link with the demo mentioned above (this project was tested directly on pc) and still not working.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I designed a HTML app that uses `jQuery` and `d3.js`. If I try to load and use them in a QWebView, they work as expected. But then, I added `tipsy` and it didn't work, although, outside QWebView, everything works fine. I suspect this relates to both the validity of the HTML being generated and some overlapping/conflicts between the functions called from the JS files, but I haven't digged deeper into it... I'll keep an eye out on this question...